# Convert all angular .styl files to normal scss or css

Tags: css, angular, stylus

Is there something fast to change all project .styl (stylus) file to scss or css ? Like console command or something ? Because I have to edit project which styles are in .styl and It's really confusing.. Who does that nowadays ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/esbullington/e1693a091533606095bb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
1) ng config defaults.styleExt=scss
2) Rename your existing .css/stylus files to .scss
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if still relevant, but using the following script you can rename all `.styl` files to `.scss` (adjust accordingly for `./css`)

```
##!/bin/bash

for file in $(find ./src -type f -name "*.styl");
do
  echo "$file";
  mv -- "$file" "${file%.styl}.scss"
done
```

The hectic part is to make sure that all the stylus syntax is changed to match sass syntax. 
Hope this helps